# How to filter a stream based on the boolean of an object

Tags: list, java-stream

I have a list of objects(cars), I want to place all the working cars first in a list and the non working ones after in the list.

the car object has a `isWorking()` getter that is equal to `true` or `false`.

```java
cars.stream()
    .filter(x->x.isWorking())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("Working Cars First" + car);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Boolean` has a natural ordering just like any other wrapper class for primitives. False comes before true. Since you want those where `isWorking()` returns true first, we need to reverse the condition.

```
car = car.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> ! x.isWorking()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("Working Cars First: " + car);
```

As Nikolas Charalambidis notes in the comment, the `Comparator` can alternatively be written `Comparator.comparing(Car::isWorking).reversed()`, which may feel more natural and more in line with usual comparators.

Comment: This is excellent! I'd rather use this comparator for sake of clarity: `Comparator.comparing(Car::isWorking).reversed()` (my personal preference).

Comment: Thanks, @Nikolas. I had considered that (you need not believe me :-) You convinced me that it’s worth mentioning in the answer, so I have edited.

Answer (score 2):

Perform *grouping* using Stream API collectors into the map `Map<Boolean, List<Car>>` and add all the lists consecutively into a new one resulting in the "working" cars appear first. Or better, use *partitioning* which is same as grouping, but is based on the boolean keys resulting in a map with two entries because of the given `Predicate`. Here is some code:

```
List<Car> cars = ...
Map<Boolean, List<Car>> resultMap = cars.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(Car::isWorking));

List<Car> orderedCars = new ArrayList<>();
orderedCars.addAll(resultMap.get(true));
orderedCars.addAll(resultMap.get(false));
```

... or with a single statement using `collectingAndThen` collector:

```
List<Car> orderedCars = cars.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.partitioningBy(Car::isWorking),
            map -> Stream.of(map.get(true), map.get(false))
                         .flatMap(List::stream)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

This solution surpasses sorting in terms of time complexity because the partitioning collector should process the list in linear time, however, we need to store more objects in memory which might not be suitable for a list of huge objects.

Comment: Thanks, @OleV.V. for raising it. Not only is this correct but it also shows an alternative way which is equally good.

Comment: @OleV.V. - That's great! You took initiative for the noble cause and succeeded. Brilliant!